# Expanding Core Data UITableView Section with only 1 row

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, expand

I have an app that uses Core Data and `NSFetchedResultsController` to create a `UITableView` with 3 sections, all based off a core data `NSString` attribute called `itemRange`. I have no problems creating or putting the items in sections, but I would like to add a particular feature that I'm not sure how to implement.

I want to be able to at first only show 1 or 2 items per section, but then have 1 more cell that says "see all" which expands the section to show all of the items.

Any ideas on how this could be implemented? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your `numberOfRowsInSection` to display the desired number of rows. Use your own variable (or array thereof) to keep track of the expanded state of each section.

Then modify `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to either show the content delivered by the fetched results controller, or show the "see all"  cell.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be what I've heard from everyone. I'll try some stuff out.